# Parse error - syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php

I've tried to diagnose this myself but I'm no programmer, really hopeful you guys can help me out. From the `functions.php` file, I'm told the issue is in the `add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');` line, but I wanted to include a larger part of the code for everyone to look at. All help is greatly appreciated!

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '...<br><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More <img class="read-more" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/read-more-arrow.jpg" alt="Read More" /></a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

// Custom excerpt length to show for like homepage small excerpts
function custom_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 100;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999);
```

Comment: By the way, what IDE do you use?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the above line with the return statement. There's an apostrophe missing at the end of the line, just before the semicolon.
That line should look like this:
`return '...<br><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More <img class="read-more" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/read-more-arrow.jpg" alt="Read More" /></a>';`

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer and help, I'm no programmer but thanks for making it easy and explaining!

Answer (score 0):

Try this(added single quote to end of return statement):

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '...<br><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More <img class="read-more" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/read-more-arrow.jpg" alt="Read More" /></a>';
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response and help, great to know there is a helpful community out there even for the simple questions like I ask!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the wrong highlighting on StackOverflow? You didn't close your string at the line which starts with `return`:

This

```
return '...<br><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More <img class="read-more" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/read-more-arrow.jpg" alt="Read More" /></a>;
```

Should be this

```
return '...<br><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More <img class="read-more" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/read-more-arrow.jpg" alt="Read More" /></a>';
```

Comment: I wouldn't have known what to look for with the highlighting, but I'll know more in the future. Thanks for the explanation!